# Is username not supposed to be showing on the top right of screen by the help and search bar?

Tags: support, display-names

[image: screenshot]

Another SO user informed me that my username was supposed to be showing so this might be a bug. I am a relatively new user so I am not certain if things have changed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. User name isn't visible, but if you hover your mouse over the image you can see it. See the official blog post:

[A New Top Bar for Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/)

> Your name has been replaced with your picture, to make it easier to
> recognize at a glance that you’re signed in as you (and because some
> longer names just don’t fit).

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I do see my name when I hover. Thank you Habib.